# Show that $P(X_t=0) = 1$ and $P(sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}X_t = 1) = 1$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $([0,1],B[0,1],\lambda)$ and let $\left\{X_t, 0 \leq t \leq 1\right\}$ be a family of random variables defined as: 
$X_t(\omega)=\begin{cases}
1 \text{ for } \mathbb\omega=t & \\ 
0 \text{ otherwise} & \end{cases}$

Show that $P(X_t=0) = 1$ and $P(sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1}X_t = 1) = 1$.

I don't understand how to solve it. Someone can give me a detailed answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints: For $P(X_t = 0)$, let's recall that this is just $P(\{\omega : X_t(\omega) = 0\})$.  Is there an easier way of writing the set $\{\omega : X_t(\omega) = 0\}$? Since your measure is just the Lebesgue measure, the probability of this event is just the Lebesgue measure of that set.

Try to think of what the function $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} X_t$ is equal to.  Fix a value of $\omega \in [0,1]$; then what is $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} X_t(\omega)$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've understood why $P(X_t = 0) = 1$. I've still trouble with the sup: I think the $sup_{0 \leq\ t \leq 1}X_t(\omega) = 1$, but isn't the Lebesgue measure of 1 = zero?

Comment: Well, what about $X_\omega(\omega)$?

Comment: I could  interpret the sup like a uninion of the whole [0,1] interval which probability is 1. Is it correct ?

Comment: @jo_no, Don't think about interpreting it just yet.  Think about how each $X_t(\omega)$ is a function of $\omega$; what value does $X_\omega(\omega)$ take?

Comment: Just the value 1 isn’t it?

Comment: Yes exactly.  So we have that $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} X_t(\omega) = 1$ since $X_\omega(\omega) = 1$.

Comment: Understood. Thank you @Marcus M